# php.ini display_errors = Off but still showing errors

Tags: php, .htaccess, mamp

I want to disable all php-warnings, errors, notices, etc. so ajax-requests don´t fail when there is an error in a script (in dev-mode).

In php.ini I´ve set `display_errors = Off`, and in `phpinfo()` display_errors shows as off (both local & global). But in my scripts I still get error-warnings. I already checked .htaccess but can´t figure out why error´s still get shown. Any help or hint?

I´m running PHP 5.6.1 using MAMP on a Mac 10.10 if that helps.

P.S: I don´t want to turn off `error_reporting` because I still want to get the errors in my log

Comment: Are you sure that the only reason that causes your AJAX request to be failed?

Comment: You need stop programming poor code's and begin write good codes. this errors will be disapear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a call to change that setting in one of the scripts you run. Most likley the case. 
Also check if a htaccess file alters any settings which could also be the case.

Comment: I thought so as well and tried to find that setting. I searched for ini_set(*) in every file but did´t find anything. Or is there another function that changes this behavior? The weird thing is that phpinfo() shows the correct setting just does the wrong thing.

Comment: Try to search for error_reporting function calls to. Error reporting settings can be a bit of a jungle at times since they can be set and altered in the ini file, source code, htaccess files etc.

Comment: What is the script or the application that you are using? @VincensvonBibra

Comment: Thanks! I found out on of the scripts I am using has an own error-handler, which printed `error_get_last();`
So I commented this out and now it works. Thanks mate!

Comment: Great, glad you found it. Can be a bit of a hassle in large systems.